Mathematical Reference for Metropolis-Within-Gibbs Algorithm
Is there a MATHEMATICAL reference for the Metropolis-Within-Gibbs algorithm with proves the algorithm mathematically ? (Presumably, the reference shall use facts in Markov Chain Theory, the fact that Metropolis-Hastings and Gibbs algorithm do generate good Markov chains, etc. )
To be precise, I am talking about the following algorithm (just to state it for completeness) :
(another reference : the accepted answer Gibbs sampling from a complex full conditional )
Suppose that $p(\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_p)$ is a joint density for Euclidean space variables $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_p$ (i.e. $\theta_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d_i}$ for some dimension $d_i$) which we need to sample from, but is difficult to do directly.
First of all, the Gibbs algorithm supposes that, for every $i = 1, \ldots, p$ the conditional densities $p(\theta_i \mid \theta_{1}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1}, \theta_{i+1}, \ldots, \theta_p)$ can be generated. The Gibbs algorithm starts by initializing arbitrarily the values $\theta_1^{(0)}, \ldots, \theta_p^{(0)}$. Suppose that $\theta_1^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_p^{(t)}$ is generated, we do :

Generate $\theta_1^{(t+1)}$ according to $p(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2 = \theta_2^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_p = \theta_p^{(t)})$.
Generate $\theta_2^{(t+1)}$ according to $p(\theta_2 \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \theta_3 = \theta_3^{(t)}\ldots, \theta_p = \theta_p^{(t)})$.
Generate $\theta_3^{(t+1)}$ according to $p(\theta_3 \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \theta_2 = \theta_2^{(t+1)}, \theta_4 = \theta_4^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_p = \theta_p^{(t)})$.

So on and so forth. That is, $\theta_i^{(t+1)}$ will be generated by $p(\theta_i \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)}, \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_p = \theta_p^{(t)})$.
When $t$ is sufficiently large, $(\theta_1^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_p^{(t)})$ can be treated as sampled from the joint distribution.
Now suppose that there is a non-empty set $I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, p\}$ (usually just one or two elements) such that, for each $i \in I$, $p(\theta_i \mid \theta_{1}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1}, \theta_{i+1}, \ldots, \theta_p)$ is not easy to generate. The Metropolis-Within-Gibbs algorithm solves this problem by using ONE Metropolis-Hastings step in place of Gibbs step.
More precisely, for $i \in I$, we fix a family of proposal/instrumental distributions parametrized by $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_p$. Call it $q_i$.
When $i \notin I$ and the above Gibbs algorithm asks us to generate $\theta_i^{(t+1)}$, do it as stated in the above algorithm. When $i \in I$ and the above Gibbs algorithm asks us to generate $\theta_i^{(t+1)}$, we do the following :

Generate a value $\theta^*$ according to the distribution $q_i(\cdot \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)}, \theta_{i} = \theta_i^{(t)}, \theta_{i+1} =\theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_{p} = \theta_p^{(t)})$.
Define :

\begin{equation*}
L = \frac{p(\theta_{i} = \theta^* \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)},  \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_{p} = \theta_{p}^{(t)})}{p(\theta_{i} = \theta_{i}^{(t)} \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)}, \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_{p} = \theta_{p}^{(t)})}
\end{equation*}
And :
\begin{equation*}
T = \frac{q_i(\theta_i^{(t)} \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)}, \theta_{i} = \theta^*, \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_{p} = \theta_{p}^{(t)})}{q_i(\theta^* \mid \theta_1 = \theta_1^{(t+1)}, \ldots, \theta_{i-1} = \theta_{i-1}^{(t+1)}, \theta_{i} = \theta_i^{(t)}, \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \ldots, \theta_{p} = \theta_{p}^{(t)})}
\end{equation*}
Put $p = \min (1, LT)$. If $LT$ is undefined due to zero denomiantor, put $p = 1$.

Set $\theta_{i}^{(t+1)} = \theta^*$ with probability $p$. Set $\theta_{i}^{(t+1)} = \theta_{i}^{(t)}$ with probability $1-p$.


Most textbooks provide a rigorous proof of the stationarity of the Metropolis-Within-Gibbs Markov kernel, including ours.

If you take the selected index for updating $i$ to be random with some distribution, there is nothing special about metropolis-hastings-within-gibbs (MHWG). It's quite simply just another MH proposal. It thus has the standard properties of the MH algorithm and any standard proof of the correct behavior of MH applies to MHWG.
If $i$ is taken sequentially in some fashion, I don't know of an easy way to derive that the behavior is still correct, but everything is still fine. I would not know how to prove this without handwaving that we have $d$ separate operators transforming distributions into distributions, and that the only fixed point is the desired one and that every other distribution is going to be modified by at least one of these operators.
Maybe someone with more experience of the details of the proofs can chime in with something better?

Under the positivity assumption required by the Hammersley-Clifford Theorem, the regular Gibbs sampler is stationary wrt the joint distribution and converging.
Adding a Metropolis step instead of simulating directly from the conditional distribution does not modify the stationarity of the joint distribution provided the Metropolis step is irreducible and the whole sampler is thus converging for the same reason.
